# IIS 「管理サービスの委任」が開けない

Tags: iis

Microsoft Web Deployによるリモートデプロイ環境を構築中です。

MWDeployのインストールからIISユーザの作成等を行った後、
ローカルのVisual StudioからのWeb配置を試そうとしたところ、
接続確認でエラーとなりました。

調べてみたところ、IISの「管理サービスの委任」の設定が必要だということがわかり
設定を行おうとしたのですが、当該機能を開こうとすると下記のエラーが発生し設定が行えません。

「この操作の実行中にエラーが発生しました。
詳細:
ファイル名
C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\config\administration.config
エラー:スキーマが見つからないため、構成セクション
'sysytem.webServer/management/delegation'を読み取れません。」

まずは、上記エラーの解消方法をご教示いただけると助かります。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/131168

Comment: `sysytem.webServer/,anagement/delegation`ではなく`system.webServer/management/delegation`ではないですか?Web Deploy v3.6をアンインストールして3.5をインストールしたらうまくいくかもしれません.この先それで本当に良いかは知りませんが.

Comment: ご指摘の通り"system.webServer/management/delegation"です。失礼しました。また、WebDeployのバージョンを3.5でインストールしなおしたら解決しました。値千金の助言、ありがとうございました！